# How can I read all csv file data into an array of structs, sequentially?

Tags: arrays, c, csv, struct

I want to read a `.csv` file. I already learned about parsing and using `strtok` to parsing. I also already wrote the code, but my code not working properly. My code only reads some part of the data to the array of struct and the other part not written to array of struct. My code also strangely read the data from line 2931, not from the beginning.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char location[100];
    char city[100];
    int price;
    int room;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
} data;

int main() {

    data house[4000];

    FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    char buffer[1000];
    fgets(buffer, 1000, file);
    int n = 0; 
    while (fgets(buffer, 1000, file)) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].location, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].city, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].price = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].room = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].bathroom = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].carpark = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].type, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        strcpy(house[n].furnish, token);

        n++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         printf("%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s\n",
                house[i].location, house[i].city, house[i].price,
                house[i].room, house[i].bathroom, house[i].carpark,
                house[i].type, house[i].furnish);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the link of the [data.csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aku57Ir1WmIgc8i1qVN8DK2yras?e=VbbuDu) my program just read about 1010 data from the actual 3940 data. [This is the image of comparison.](https://imgur.com/Zkx513w)

[This is from the terminal, which shown the data from line 2931, not from the beginning.](https://imgur.com/K0aIh4U)

I think I have to mention this: after successfully reading the data, what I want to do is create some menu that contains [like this](https://imgur.com/a/gGcRyli). So the program could do some of things like displaying the data, searching the data, sort the data, and export the data after being sorted. Is the use of an array of structs like this in my code already correct to do all of the tasks I mentioned? Or I can change to somethings more effective and efficient?

Comment: can't reproduce. I've compiled your program, downloaded data.csv and run it and the only difference is the missing title line in the output

Comment: Nothing wrong with the program .... the reason it only starts at 2999 or somthing is that the console output has run out of lines to print to on windows you can set it by clicking the console going to properties and increasing the screen buffer size by adding more lines

Comment: Using `strtok()` is unlikely to be correct if you ever have to deal with CSV data that has commas inside quoted strings.

Comment: @JonoJames yeah. I just found out the issue with my terminal in vscode. When i try to run the code in devc++ in cmd, it works fine. thank you for reminding me.

Comment: `scanf` was written to consume this kind of files, and I believe you should use it: it is way more easier. Your program output is text, your input file is text, so you could post here a short csv content and also the program output, instead of multiple links for outside things

Comment: Problem solved. The issue is just the scrollback settings in my vscode is limited to 1000, so the data showing just 1000 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a file data you could use the fgets libs

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
 
const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
{
    const char* data;
    for (data = strtok(line, ";");
            data && *data;
            data = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return data;
    }
    return NULL;
}
 
int main()
{
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);
        printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

To write css to a file you could use the cout methods or ofstream

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>



int main()
{

    std::ofstream Myfile("boogaloo.txt");

    int width =10, height =10;
      

    for (int w = 0; w< width;w++)
    {   
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            Myfile << h<< ",";
        }

        Myfile << "\n ";
    }

    Myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

your code looks good to me however you console is running out of lines to print the data to . so click on the console if on windows go to proporties and increase the buffer size to print to . I did it with buffer height .
[image]

Comment: `std::ofstream Myfile("boogaloo.txt");`?  For a **C** program?

Comment: Yea just scraped the code from existing code I use

Comment: thank you, but i'm not using c++ to create this program.

Comment: for the console, yes you right. The issue is the console/terrminal in my vscode. it works fine when i use devc++ cmd. thank you for reminding me about this. i think i have to configure my vscode terminal.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` might be inappropriate for parsing the CSV contents: sequences of consecutive separators will be considered a single separator.  This might be OK for whitespace, but not for `,` as empty fields will cause desynchronisation of the parser.  In any case, you should check that the return values of `strtok()` are not null before passing them to `atoi()` or `strcpy`.

You could also use `sscanf()` to parse the line in a single step and report parsing failures, but `sscanf()` cannot parse empty fields either.  It is still a simpler way to check for invalid records.

Also note these remarks:

- you must check for `fopen` failure are report a meaningful message
- you must not read more records than would fit in the destination array
- `strcpy` might cause buffer overflows as you do not check if the string fields fit in the destination arrays.
- allocating 1665000 bytes of automatic storage might exceed your target environment limit. Consider allocating the `house` object.

Here is a modified version that will report invalid CSV records:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char location[100];
    char city[100];
    int price;
    int room;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
} data;

int main(void) {

    int max_n = 4000;
    data *house = calloc(sizeof(*house), max_n);
    if (house == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate database\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "data.csv", strerror(errno));
        free((house);
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[1000];
    int lineno = 1;
    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:empty file\n", "data.csv");
        fclose(file);
        free((house);
        return 1;
    }
    int n = 0; 
    while (n < max_n && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
        char eol[2];
        lineno++;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%99[^,],%99[^,\n]%1[\n]",
            house[n].location, house[n].city, &house[n].price,
            &house[n].room, &house[n].bathroom, &house[n].carpark,
            house[n].type, house[n].furnish, eol) == 9) {
            n++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: invalid record: %s\n", "data.csv", lineno, buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s\n",
               house[i].location, house[i].city, house[i].price,
               house[i].room, house[i].bathroom, house[i].carpark,
               house[i].type, house[i].furnish);
    }

    free((house);
    return 0;
}
```

You link to an inaccessible screenshot that supposedly shows only lines from 2931 to the end (3939 lines?). The likely explanation is simple: the program is very fast and the output produced so quickly that you only get a chance to see the last lines, all previous ones having scrolled off the top, beyond the scrollback threshold.  Use the scroolbars (if any) to try and see previous output or pipe your program to `head` to get the first few lines of output or to `more` to page through the output, or `wc` to count output lines.